Isaiah 9:6 Translation: Jewish vs Christian
This question Regarding Isaiah 9:6, which text has the original rendering, LXX or MT, and why does the false rendering differ significantly from the original? prompted the current question concerning the difference between Jewish and Christian translators of Isaiah 9:6
Typical Christian Translation:

(BSB) For unto us a child is born, unto us a son is given, and the
government will be upon His shoulders. And He will be called Wonderful
Counselor, Mighty God, Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace.

Jewish Translation from here >> https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15940/jewish/Chapter-9.htm :

For a child has been born to us, a son given to us, and the authority
is upon his shoulder, and the wondrous adviser, the mighty God, the
everlasting Father, called his name, "the prince of peace."

What are the grammatical justifications for each translation of the Hebrew text?

see this answer.  The issue seems to boil down to whether or not 'So vayikra shmoh tony,' could be "and he called his name tony", or "and tony called his name". So vayikra is not always translated 'and he called'  - it can be that the subject comes one or two words later.' https://i.sstatic.net/rcXMz.png

The Hebrew translation is the correct one, and the orthodox Christian translation is also correct, but is misunderstood according to Trinitarian misinterpretation.
Isaiah 9:5(6)b may be translated,

And he is called "A Wonderful Counsellor is the Mighty God, An Everlasting Father is the Prince of Peace."

But I think Isaiah 9:5(6)b should be translated,

And he is called Wonderful Counsellor, Mighty God, Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace.

All four epithets belong solely to God the Father, but are here attributed to the Son, because the Father is actually inside of the Son, and the Son is the direct agent of God as the mediator to men.
The Son is the exact Image of God, and therefore when one sees the Son, they indirectly see God the Father through him.
The Son is appropriately called the titles of the Father God because he is God's exact representative to men, and the Spirit of the Father himself resides within the Son.
Isaiah 9:5(6)b does not imply that Jesus is God, but that the Mighty God is in Christ, and God interfaces with us through Christ.
