Mistranslation of Isaiah 9:6
In this passage, the word "way-yiq-rā" is translated as "will be called"

For unto us a Child is born,
Unto us a Son is given;
And the government will be upon His shoulder.
And His name will be called (way-yiq-rā)
Wonderful, Counselor, Mighty God,
Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace"

However, "way-yiq-rā" means "will call" (active voice), while "will be called" (passive voice) is "way-yiq-qā-rê"

God called (way-yiq-rā) the light Day, and the darkness He called Night. So the evening and the morning were the first day (Genesis 1:5)
So Hagar bore Abram a son; and Abram called (way-yiq-rā) his son, whom Hagar bore, Ishmael (Genesis 16:15)


and of the priests: the sons of Habaiah, the sons of Koz, the sons of Barzillai, who took a wife of the daughters of Barzillai the Gileadite, and was called (way-yiq-qā-rê) by their name (Nehemiah 7:63)
Then I said to them, ‘What is this [e]high place to which you go?’ So its name is called (way-yiq-qā-rê) Bamah to this day" (Ezekiel 20:29)

Therefore, this verb needs a subject and Isaiah 9:6 then translates as:

For unto us a Child is born, Unto us a Son is given; And the government will be upon His shoulder. And Wonderful, Counselor, Mighty God, Everlasting Father will call his name Prince of Peace

And as you noticed, in other verses it is translated in the past tense
Question
Is this passage commonly mistranslated? Is the alternative translation given above the best translation given the verb "way-yiq-rā"?

What‘s your question?

To comment if I am right or wrong

Just to say that this site is not for comments, as such. It is for a specific question to be given specific answers from the community, then the OP can give the green tick to whichever one (if any) answered the question most usefully. "Yes" or "No" answers are disallowed, so you need to ask  what it is that you seek to better understand.

This is essentially the same question as https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/99847/isaiah-96-translation-jewish-vs-christian

Rabbi Shimon Schwab translates it thus:

For a child has been born to us, a son has been given to us; and the
authority will rest on his shoulder, and He — Who is marvelous of
counsel, the Almighty God, the father of all eternity — will call him
the prince of peace.

"The Almighty God, the father of all eternity — will call him the prince of peace. In our
translation, we have followed Targum and Rashi and taken these three phrases as
referring to HaKadosh Baruch Hu (God the Father)."
"Radak makes the point, however, that these phrases could just as well be taken as a description of Chizkiyahu, the future king: ץ ֵיוֹע א ֶל ֶפּ, a man of marvelous intellect and counsel; גּבּוֹר לִ ֵא, a powerful ruler [as in י ִ ד י ל ֵא ְ ל שֶׁי, It is within the power of my hand (Bereishis 31:29)]; ד ע י ִב ֲא, the father of eternity, in the sense that, ideally, with his rule the epoch of Mashiach would begin, and this would last for the duration of the existence of the world."
Source:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://blog.artscroll.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/rav-shwab_pages1.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiF3YKc76-KAxUzLtAFHbvdHiQQFnoECBQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0XzJZWaINulLd9joRf6J7Z
See also Daniel Wee's insight:
https://www.tsebi.com/2016/11/11/the-prince-of-peace-isa-96/

Interesting find ! This verse is fullfilled in Luke. "He will be great, and will be called the Son of the Highest; and the Lord God will give Him the throne of His father David" (Luke 1:32, NKJV) .
Reference
The Holy Bible, NKJV. (1982). Thomas Nelson, Inc.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics. In order to answer the OP, please use the context of this verse given in the question and show how Isaiah 9:6 either has been mistranslated or has not been mistranslated. In other words, consider the context of the question and answer according to this context. As it is, your answer might be correct, but not dynamically answering the actual question. Consider checking out the Help Center for better ways to answer: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer
